# Find some kind of generating functions for odd Hermite polynomials

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, polynomials, orthogonal-polynomials, hermite-polynomials

**Question:** I am looking at the following series:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty t^n \cdot \frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n+1)!}\cdot H_{2n+1}(x), $$ which can also be written as
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty u^n \cdot \frac{1}{(2n+1)!}\cdot H_{2n+1}(x)H_{2n}(0)$$ where $H_n$ are the Hermite polynomials and $t,u$ are some complex numbers.  My goal is to somehow simplify it. Ideally, it should look similar to the usual type of genereting functions of the Hermite polynomials. So far, I tried using the Mehler Hermite polynomial formula [See Wolfram Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MehlersHermitePolynomialFormula.html) along with some recurrence relations but I cannot seem to avoid the problem that I only sum over the odd (or only over the even) polynomials.

```
    Does someone have a better idea how to approach this problem?
```

Comment: Use that these polynomials are all odd?

Comment: Could you elaborate? I am honestly not experienced at all in this topic. I think it should be rather straight-forward to simplify the sum without the double-factorial, but with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try and get a closed form for
$$ F(x,y,z) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(z/2)^k}{k!} H_{k}(x)H_{k-1}(y). $$
Since $H_{k-1}(0)$ is zero if $n$ is even, this reduces to your sum in the case $y=0$. Differentiating with respect to $x$ gives, via $H'_{k}(x) = 2k H_{k-1}(x)$,
$$ F_x = 2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(z/2)^k}{(k-1)!} H_{k-1}(x)H_{k-1}(y) = z \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(z/2)^k}{k!} H_{k}(x)H_{k}(y) \\
= \frac{z}{\sqrt{1-z^2}} \exp{\left( \frac{2xyz-(x^2+y^2)z^2}{1-z^2} \right)} $$
from Mehler's formula. It remains to put $y=0$ and integrate. So,
$$ F_x(x,0,z) = \frac{z}{\sqrt{1-z^2}} \exp{\left( -x^2\frac{z^2}{1-z^2} \right)}. $$
We know all about this: it's just a Gaussian. Therefore its integral is related to the error function. $F(0,0,z)=0$ since one or the other polynomial is zero for each integer. Indeed, from here it follows that
$$ F(x,0,z) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \operatorname{erf}{\left( \frac{xz}{\sqrt{1-z^2}} \right)}, $$
where of course
$$ \operatorname{erf}{(w)} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^{w} e^{-t^2}\, dt. $$
That is probably about as simple as it gets, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had similar approach in my mind when I woke up today.  My proof for the uniform convergence required for the switching of lim and d/dx is somewhat sloppy, but I should be able to figure that out by own. Also, I suppose that it is hopeless to look for an easier form, as this would mean I could simplify the expression you gave, which would mean I could simplify the errofunction itself...

Comment: I have one more question regarding Mehler's formula: For complex $z$, which sqare root is meant by $\sqrt{1-z^2}$?

Comment: The function has essential singularities at $z=\pm 1$, so the series only converges for $|z|<1$. There, it's just the branch that is $1$ when $z=0$.

Comment: Which function do you mean? The closed-form functions have movable singularities for $z=\pm1$. Nevertheless, I am not able to find a dominating function (for Lesbesgue's dominated convergence theorem) for the case |z|=1, which is the case I am most interested at. Unfortunately, I have not found too much about the conditions of Mehler's formula, but I have found publications where it is applied for $|z|=1$. Is this not allowed? Again, I do not see any essential singularities.

Comment: Further, if this sum converges for $|z|=1$, do you have an idea how to find a dominating function? I would like to say that the absolute value $\sum_{n=0}^N(z/2)^n\cdot H_{n}(x)\cdot H_{n}(0)/(n!)$ is smaller than some integrable function for all $N$, but pulling the absolute value inside the sum is a too strong estimate (for |z|=1). But since each of the 3 factors in the sum freqently changes its sign, a different approach seems somewhat tough.

Comment: https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=heCzfIclio0C&lpg=PA51&pg=PA51#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: Thank you. The pubilcation in which I found it used for $|z|=1$ is [link](http://www.fst.umac.mo/en/staff/documents/fstkik/FSKS07.pdf), are there justifications for this? I've read through some other proofs and they all required $|z|<1$. However, in the book you linked I do not understand why (4.15) requires $|r|$<1. 
Also, just to make sure, in my case, where $y=0$, I do have movable singularities only, right?